# Vue - Axios Error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm making a Crud using Vue and axios.

My "create component" is working fine, but I have a problem with my "edit component".

The two components are the same except that the edit one have a parameter on the URL ("myweb.com?id=3") and on mounted cycle I make an axios call to retrieve the register data.

```
mounted() {
this.$http.get("/api/getOrder?id=" + this.order).then((response) => {
     this.complements = response.data
}); ...
```

I get this error "::: TypeError: this.$http is undefined" that break my code.

In my axios.js I have my prototype defined which is working fine on the rest of components:

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axiosIns
```

The weird thing is that this error only appear on production (not on local) and is intermittent (sometimes it works correctly, sometimes fails ... no pattern found)

EDIT ::
I realize that if I remove the axios call from mounted and put it on a button-method it works perfectly

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: Did you import axios.js in main.js?

Comment: yes, I do. As I say in my Edit ... if I call axios in a method (tfrom a button click) there is no error .. but not working on mounted()

Comment: Can you add how you create axiosIns? What is axiosIns?

Comment: const axiosIns = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://xxxx.xxxxxx.es/',
  timeout: 1000,
  withCredentials: true,
})

Comment: Can you try `const _self = this;` and then use `_self.$http`